# Getting more results per page on YouTube

Tags: url, search, youtube

I have a script I'm building, and I need an easy way to get a list of ALL URLs returned by YouTube to a given query.
Right now I have to manually go from one results' page to the next and extract the data from each of the pages separately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "ALL URLs". You could use the Zend GData YouTube API to search for videos and parse the results into something you need. However, there is no way how to get all results at once. All feeds are limited to 999 as far as I know...

Comment: @user1173974 Did you find a way to return a large  number of URLs